# C++ variadic template indicates compile errors after 2 years of working without errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20

VS 2022 17.4.4: Doing some refresh on 2 year old source, certain templates, now, indicate a lot of errors.
This simple template below was just to avoid typing:
`std::cout << std::format(..)`  by replacing by a simple:
`fcout(..)`

```
template<typename ...TArgs>
void fcout(const char* sFormat, TArgs&&... args)
{
    std::cout << std::format(sFormat, args...);
}

void test_fcout(void)
{
    double x = 10, y = 20, z = x*y;
    fcout("{} = {}; L={}, l={}", "Surface", z, x, y);
    fcout("{}", "Test");
}
```

Errors indicated:

> error C7595: 'std::_Basic_format_string<char,const char
> (&)[5]>::_Basic_format_string': call to immediate function is not a
> constant expression
>
> message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its
> lifetime
>
> message : see usage of 'sFormat'
>
> message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void
> fcout<const char(&)[5]>(const char *,const char (&)[5])' being
> compiled

I spent hours to fix it, but never succeed. What did I wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: What does "do not work anymore" mean?

Comment: `std::format` requires a compile time string and `sformat` can't guarantee that it has one.

Comment: The errors - live - https://godbolt.org/z/3W84EKGxh

Comment: @Sam and Nathan: you are right I am not accurate enough, I complete the question...

Comment: Frankly, I don't see the point in putting a -1: I guarantee you that I did extensive research, the question is absolutely legitimate (I recall that the templates worked for years), and the term "work" is absolutely clear for me (non english born). Fortunately, Remy has seen the point, and thank him again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) doc on cppreference.com:

> As of [P2216R3](https://wg21.link/P2216R3), it is an error if the format string is not a constant expression. [`std::vformat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/vformat) can be used in this case.

P2216R3 was implemented in Visual Studio 2022 v17.2.

So, try this instead:

```
template<typename ...TArgs>
void fcout(std::string_view sFormat, TArgs&&... args)
{
    std::cout << std::vformat(sFormat, std::make_format_args(args...));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Remy, it worked absolutely fine !